How do I fix 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' in swift?
I am working on an app using coreData and a log in. For that, I have a LoginView and LoginViewModel that I use to get the info to the ContentView. I keep getting this error message: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[abcText2Speech.UserEntity firstname]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000017f14c0'"
Here is my code where I think the issue lies :
this is from LoginViewModel:
func signup()-\> (UserEntity, Int){
    @StateObject var dataController = DataController.shared

    buttonState = .loading(title: "Loading", systemImage: "person")
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1.5){
        if self.isValidEmail() && self.isValidPassword() && self.isValidName(){
            self.isLoggedIn = true
            dataController.addUser(firstname: self.fname, lastname: self.lname, email: self.email, password: self.password)
            
            print("signed in")
            print(dataController.savedEntities[(dataController.savedEntities.count)-1].email ?? "email")
            print(self.isLoggedIn)
            self.buttonState = .enabled(title: "Login", systemImage: "checkmark.circle")
        } else{
            self.buttonState = .disabled(title: "Fill out all fields to log in", systemImage: "exclamationmark.circle")
        }
    }
    print("Test")
    print(dataController.savedEntities[(dataController.savedEntities.count)-1].email ?? "email")
        
    return (dataController.savedEntities[(dataController.savedEntities.count)-1], 1)

}

and this all prints with no issue.
this is the relevant part of sign up view
ActionButton(state: $model.buttonState, onTap:{
    signup = model.signup()
    user = signup.0

                    }, backgroundColor: .primary , foregroundColor: Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
                    )
                    NavigationLink (destination: LoginView()){
                        Text("Already have a profile? Click here to Log in")
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Label("Welcome!", systemImage: "hand.wave")
            }
            .padding()
            .textFieldStyle(.plain)
            let keyboard = abcTextViewModel()
            
            NavigationLink (destination: ContentView(viewModel: keyboard, currentUser: user) , isActive: $model.isLoggedIn){
                
                EmptyView()
            }`

and this is the part of Content view that breaks it
Text(currentUser.firstname ?? "name")

these are the details of UserEntity
and this is the DataController code
import Foundation
import CoreData

class DataController: ObservableObject{
static let shared = DataController()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    @Published var savedEntities: [UserEntity] = []
    
    init(){
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        fetchUsers()
    }
    
    func fetchUsers() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<UserEntity>(entityName: "UserEntity")
        
        do {
            savedEntities = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error while fetching: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func addUser(firstname: String, lastname: String, email: String, password: String) {
        let newUser = UserEntity(context: container.viewContext)
        newUser.firstname = firstname
        newUser.lastname = lastname
        newUser.email = email
        newUser.id = password
        saveData()
    }
    
    func saveData(){
        do {
            try container.viewContext.save()
            fetchUsers()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error saving: \(error)")
        }
    } }

any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on this one error for quite a while
This is where the code sends the error (on the struct abcText2SpeechApp line):
import SwiftUI

@main
struct abcText2SpeechApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup{
            SignUpView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, DataController.shared.container.viewContext)
            
                
        }
        
    }
}

I tried printing the user details in login view model which worked, however that did not carry over to content view.

Please spend some time formatting your code correctly.

Please pinpoint the actual line of code in which the crash occurs.

What is currentUser and how is it set?

current user is set to be the output of the signup() function as shown in the code

That error message means you are trying to call a method on an object that has been deallocated. You're using a function, method, or accessor on a variable, but that variable doesn't have a valid object anymore.
If the line is
Text(currentUser.firstname ?? "name")

Then it means that currentUser does not have a valid object. Maybe it did once, but it doesn't when the crash happens.
Why this happens is not clear from the code you posted. There is no currentUser variable anywhere in the code except on that one line, so it's impossible to say where that variable is defined, where it gets its value, or why the object might be deallocated.

Hi, thank you for the help! Current user is defined in the 1st and 2nd code block — user is the result of the signup function and then ContentView is called with currentUser passed in as a parameter. It is accessed by contentView as an observable object like this: @ObservedObject var currentUser: UserEntity

Yes, and it’s getting deallocated somewhere. This isn’t a Core Data problem, it’s down to basic memory management trouble.

The signup function makes an asynchronous call so what is returned is not the newly created user but something else and perhaps later this returns a different user from savedEntities when the asynchronous call is complete?
